# Настройка wi-fi

Tags: сеть, wifi, сервер

Помогите, пожалуйста, настроить wi-fi. Есть сервер он выступает роутером, интернет к нему подключен через модем. От сервера идет кабель в коммутатор, к нему уже и подключены все компы. Нужно настроить вай-фай. Есть точка доступа. Мне не понятно только куда ее уже подключать, к коммутатору, к серверу или к любому компьютеру?

Comment: Модель точки доступа?

Comment: D-Link 2100AP

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Зависит от функционала wifi устройства:

- если оно умеет роутить и поднимать
     интернет(через модем) то можно вместо
     сервера
- если умеет делать
     зеркалирование то подключить в
     коммутатор
- если нужно только двухточечное соединение то можно к любому
     компу или серверу

Оптимальным (даже с учетом недостатка информации по требования к сети) мне видится следующая схема:
инет <-> модем <-> [ сервер-шлюз ]

[сервер-шлюз (rj45)]  <-> коммутатор  <-> пользователи локалки

[сервер-шлюз (usb/или тоже rj45)]  <-> wifi точка доступа  <-> пользователи WIFI

При таком раскладе понадобится настроить на сервере-шлюзе новую подсеть для wifi пользователей(NAT,Маршрутизацию, DHCP,фильтрация),
а wifi точка доступа должна уметь работать как прозрачный сетевой мост, так же
если особых требований по разделению трафика(LAN, WLAN) нет то можно точку доступа подключить к коммутатору.

*ps судя по вопросам вам лудше доверить работу специалисту, либо потратить часов 4-5 на разбор механизмов работы ЛВС.*

Comment: спасибо большое за хорошее разъяснение,я бы покопался поскольку собираюсь поступать на программиста и очень интересуюсь всем этим, всю сетку делал в офисе, и у товарища wi-fi настраивал,а тут уже не смог,нет времени,вызвал сегодня мастера буду смотреть что и как он там будет делать

Answer (score 0):

Мне очень нравится программа [Connectify](http://www.softportal.com/software-19112-connectify.html).

"Небольшая бесплатная утилита, с помощью которой можно легко превратить ПК под управлением Windows 7 или Windows Server 2008 R2 в хот-спот Wi-Fi, а также быстро развернуть беспроводную сеть и организовать доступ в Интернет для нескольких портативных устройств (например смартфон, коммуникатор, нетбук и др.). Для удобства пользователя в программе присутствует встроенный Мастер начальной настройки, а для обеспечения безопасности связи применяется шифрование WPA2-PSK или WEP."